# Is it possible to see all publicly-accessible files on a website?

Tags: web-scraping, download, file-sharing

I would like to query a website that provides files for download to see all the available files for download.

For example: webpage called `https://download.website.com/path/to/file` has a `file` of interest to me, but I would also like to see other available files available in the system **publicly**.

Essentially I would like to be able to view a hierarchy of all of the publicly-facing files given some parent link. So if I know I want all files stored under `https://download.website.com/path/`, the query would turn up a recursive list of available files from `https://download.website.com/path/*`.

Is this even possible to do for most websites? Would allowing this behavior be too compromising to web frameworks in general, so it might not exist? Am I XYing out of control?

Any help here greatly appreciated.

Comment: Generally speaking, it's not possible.  Some web servers may serve an "index listing" of directories, but the setting is commonly disabled today.

Answer (score 0):

This method isn't perfect, but you can try it. Just put this query in Google Search.
You can do a Google search for some publicly available and indexed path.
For example if you want to search all available page on a website/domain:

```
site:download.website.com
```

If you want to search all PDF files in this site:

```
site:download.website.com filetype:pdf
```

If you want to search all links with path `download.website.com/wp-content/`:

```
site:download.website.com inurl:/wp-content/
```

I hope it will help you a little bit.

Comment: This worked for some files (! yes !), but not others. The files that this worked for are files viewable by the browser on a page (pdf,txt,html), it did not find all the data files (zip,tar,etc.).